# Prevent duplicated ID entry in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I have a set up a constructor in a `Book` class, and another class I have set up an ArrayList of type `Book`. The book expects to receive a `title`, `author`, `bookID`, `copies`, `timesLoaned`, `onLoan`.

I am looking to find the most efficient way to ensure that there are no duplicated `bookID` before adding a book. I have not learned about `Map` etc, so would like to avoid this for now. I was thinking about the use of a for loop to check the `bookID's` before adding.

Below is my addBook method:

```
    // Adding a book to ArrayList
public void addBook(){
    System.out.println("==============================");
    // Getting user input and assigns it to variables
    System.out.print("Enter a title: ");
    String title = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter an author: ");
    String author = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter quantity of books: ");
    int quantity = checkInput(sc); // checks for valid integer

    // Generates random ID for book
    int bookID = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000);

    // Adding book the the ArrayList, using user input taken above
    newBook.add(new Book(title, author, bookID, quantity, 0, false));

    // Adding to maxReturns for returnBook()
    maxReturns.add(quantity);

    // Testing that it has added - TAKE OUT AFTER COMPLETION
    for(int i = 0; i < newBook.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(newBook.get(i).getBookID() + " " + newBook.get(i).getTitle());
    }

    // Showing its been added
    System.out.println("Book has been added!"); 
    System.out.println("==============================");
}
```

Comment: why not using Map<Integer,Book> ?

Comment: @StefanBeike _I have not learned about Map etc, so would like to avoid this for now._

Comment: Can't you implement a method called getBookById and use that id to see if that returns anything. If returned, then you generate new ID, if not, then use that.

Comment: So you refuse to learn the simple data structure that solves your problem exactly?

Comment: If not using Maps, then you can keep another ArrayList that holds the book ids. Before adding the book you do a `contains(newBookId)` if not there, then you are safe to add it in both arrays.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to not use a map, I can't believe you guys are suggesting anything else...

Comment: @redFIVE, It's not that I am refusing. I am still a student and we have not been taught this so I cannot use it as a method of a validating my code as of yet. I know it would be a much better option to use, I just cannot use it as of yet.

Comment: Why not? Are you not allowed? You are asking for the most efficient way of doing this, but thinking of loops which is the most inefficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also suggest a Map, but if you want to use an ArrayList you should think that ArrayList implements the List interface, which has a contains method. You could thus just query whether your ArrayList contains the new book. The contains method will then loop through the ArrayList using the equals method to check whether each book is equal to the new one you want to compare against. It would be a good idea to (correctly) override your Book's HashCode in a safe way.